# Is there any interest in a proof proofreading site?

Tags: discussion, area51, solution-verification

I envision a site where people could post their proofs -- either as answers to textbook exercises or revisions of current textbook proofs -- and get feedback on which parts might need improving, and perhaps how this might be done.

This sort of site could be useful to a number of people. Namely, it would be useful to 1) students looking to improve their proof-writing skills, or reinforce their understanding, and 2) those writing textbooks who want to try out their writing on the public.

This sort of thing doesn't seem quite right for the current math.SE and I don't know of any sites where it would fit.

My questions to you all are

a) Is this something that you have an interest in or that you think would be useful?

b) Can math.SE be used for these sort of questions? If not, is this sort of question appropriate for the SE format in general? Are there sites out there that *do* fit proof questions like this?

I know that codereview.SE fulfills this need to some degree for programming, but its scope is limited to best practices.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much what the [tag:proof-verification] tag is already used for, especially when the asker requests critIques on the writing?

Comment: Some related older discussions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/questions-that-ask-to-verify-solution-to-problem

Comment: But IIRC none of the older discussions discussed possibility of creating a separate site for this. (I do not know how codereview.SE works, so I cannot say whether the model of that site would be suitable for mathematics.)

Comment: I have added ([meta-tag:area51]) tag, since the question discusses possible site proposal. (Also such a proposal is not posted on area51.) If you think that this is not good use of the tag or you can improve the tagging in any way, please, edit the post.

Comment: Even if these is any sense in this (and I believe there is), I think - and correct me if I'm wrong - that authors and lecturers dislike having the solutions to the problems in the books available to students, unfortunately. I thus see no future in your idea. The proof/solution-verfication tags alone do not come close to the possibilities a separate website could  give, namely tagging by author and title of the books. And I only realised midway through this comment that this is an old question.

Comment: @GitGud You are probably aware that *solution-manuals-like* posts have been discussed on meta. See [Creating a solutions manual within a single math.SE question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/), [Centralized solutions to textbook problems considered harmful?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/), [Categorizing homework questions with textbook information in a way that makes the site act like a solutions manual](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218/) and maybe also some other posts, which are linked to those two questions.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I wasn't aware. Thanks. I'll take a look at the links.